# Make sure string is a valid CSS ID name

Tags: php, css

I have a bunch of database records (without auto_increment IDs or anything else like that) rendered as a list, and it came to pass that I need to differentiate each of them with a unique `id`.

I could just add a running counter into the loop and be done with it, but unfortunately this ID needs to be cross-referenceable throughout the site, however the list is ordered or filtered.

Therefore I got an idea to include the record title as a part of the `id` (with a prefix so it doesn't clash with layout elements).

How could I transform a string into an `id` name in a foolproof way so that it never contains characters that would break the HTML or not work as valid CSS selectors?

For example;

```
Title ==> prefix_title
TPS Report 2010 ==> prefix_tps_report_2010
Mike's "Proposal" ==> prefix_mikes_proposal
#53: Míguèl ==> prefix_53_miguel
```

The titles are always diverse enough to avoid conflicts, and will never contain any non-western characters.

Thanks!

Comment: If I get your point: you have some row in a table, for each row you want to generate an HTML list item, and each item should have an unique id (HTML attribute `id` ?), this id should not break your HTML and be a valid CSS selector. Why do you need a such thing, and why are you talking about valid CSS selector ? You can't write *static* CSS selector based on *dynamic* ids.

Comment: pomeh: I need to reference individual list items with jQuery, and it's that much more easier if when printing the list, I have id's set for each item. || Rick: That's... an embarrassingly simple yet awesome solution.

Comment: I don't understand the part about "printing the list". Also, can you edit the database schema ? If so, you can add a column which could contains something like `md5( current title + date + random number )`, and the value is determined when the data is inserted in the database

Comment: `echo '<li id="'.foo($row["title"]).'">'.$row["title].'</li>';` .. and no, I can't change the DB itself, as it's part of a third party software package, and forwards compatibility could be compromised.

Comment: look at my answer, you don't need to use the ID attribute at all, what do you think ?

Answer (score 9):

I needed a similar solution for Deeplink Anchors.

Found this useful:

```
function seoUrl($string) {
    //Lower case everything
    $string = strtolower($string);
    //Make alphanumeric (removes all other characters)
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);
    //Clean up multiple dashes or whitespaces
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
    //Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11330527/3010027

*PS: Wordpress-Users have a look here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title*

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the HTML `id` attribute at all. You can use [HTML5 data-* attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) to store user defined values. Here is an example:

```
<ul class="my-awesome-list">
    <!-- PHP code, begin a for/while loop on rows -->
    <li data-rowtitle="<?php echo json_encode($row["title"]); ?>">
        <?php echo $row["title"]; ?>
    </li>
    <!-- PHP loop end -->
</ul>
```

Then, in you jQuery code, you can access the data-* values with the [`$.fn.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method

```
$(".my-awesome-list li").each(function(){
     var realTitle = $(this).data('rowtitle');
});
```

Comment: is this `data-xxxx` and $(y).data(xxxx) is a built in jQuery functionality? And how cross browser is it if so?

Comment: `data-*` attributes are defined in the HTML5 specification. However, you can use them even if your page doesn't use HTML5, they are recognized by all browsers.

Comment: But what if I wanted to select a specific `li`? Wouldn't that require looping through the list checking each item for the specific `data-*` attribute, which means I might as well just forget the attribute, and check directly against the list content?

Comment: you want to select a specific li based on what ? Its `title` value ? Can you post a more detailed example of what you're trying to do ? Because depending on the final purpose, some solutions might or might not scale

Comment: Well if each `li` has a unique ID value, then I can just do `$("#prefix_title")`. But if I store the unique stuff into a `data-*` or `title` or something, doesn't selecting that get slightly more difficult coding wise slash slow performance wise?

Comment: @EmphramStavanger it depends on what you want to do. Why do you want to selected a specific element ? In what circumstances ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [W3 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters), ids and classes can contain:

> only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] (...) plus the hyphen (-) and the
>   underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, or a hyphen followed by a digit

Note that some other characters are accepted (that I omitted for simplicity). So I use this:

```js
// We must be careful not to replace into an invalid string,
// thus adding 'a' in some cases and doing a second replace.
string.replace(/(^-\d-|^\d|^-\d|^--)/,'a$1').replace(/[\W]/g, '-');
```

Note that you may end up with identical strings that were originally different: you would have to rely on a more advance replace function if you have issues with this.