# Strip php variable, replace white spaces with dashes

Tags: php

How can I convert a PHP variable from "My company & My Name" to "my-company-my-name"?

I need to make it all lowercase, remove all special characters and replace spaces with dashes.

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 265, accepted):

This function will create an SEO friendly string

```
function seoUrl($string) {
    //Lower case everything
    $string = strtolower($string);
    //Make alphanumeric (removes all other characters)
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);
    //Clean up multiple dashes or whitespaces
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
    //Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);
    return $string;
}
```

should be fine :)

Comment: Thank you. It's a nice simple function, It would be nice to be extended to strip out certain seo-unfriendly keywords like 'the' & 'and'.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734970) suggests it's not worth stripping out 'stop' words; I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/chrisveness/7c34a3f18938f33d513c) which adds accented character handling to rory's solution.

Comment: how can i remove the first and last space without `-` symbol.?

Comment: @Kvvaradha Paste the following line as the first line in the function `$string = trim($string);` and that will solve your issue.

Comment: how to use this

Comment: @AjithChadda `seoUrl("noner SEO @@@ STrings vs_£(----");` = 'noner-SEO-STrings-vs'

Comment: @rorypicko To strip out seo-unfriendly keywords you just need to add in the following three lines: `$find = array('the","and"); //You can also enter any other keywords you would like to remove here. $replace = array(""); $string = str_replace($find,$replace,$string);`

Answer (score 9):

Replacing specific characters:
http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Example:

```
function replaceAll($text) { 
    $text = strtolower(htmlentities($text)); 
    $text = str_replace(get_html_translation_table(), "-", $text);
    $text = str_replace(" ", "-", $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[-]+/i", "-", $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Yop, and if you want to handle any special characters you'll need to declare them in the pattern, otherwise they may get flushed out. You may do it that way:

```
strtolower(preg_replace('/-+/', '-', preg_replace('/[^\wáéíóú]/', '-', $string)));
```